# Execute callback after modernizr/yepnope has loaded all files

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

I have a number of test conditions and files to load before I run the follow up scripts on my page. Is there a way to fire a callback after ALL my files are loaded?

The following is suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330130/multiple-conditions-with-yepnope) and communicates my intent but does not actually work. The function in the complete is firing before 1.js or 2.js has finished loading.

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: App.isSmallScreen,
        yep:  '1.js',
        nope: '2.js'
    },
    {
        test: App.isTouch,
        yep: '3.js'
    },
    {
        test: Modernizer.csstransitions,
        nope:4.js
    },
    {
        complete: animationInit
    }
]);
```

Comment: That sounds tricky and I'm not sure if you can do with with the framework. What might be an option is having a receiving function that is called to by 1,2,3,4 etc. (this is a bit messy though) and only calls the complete function once all have been received. Ugh, sorry if that's the solution though.

Comment: Current solution is to nest all the tests as callback functions. This might be less messy :)

Comment: Yikes. BTW doesn't all this get loaded before the 'onload' event anyways? Does animationInit have to be called before that?

Comment: The test is currently executed on DOMReady, and the animations initialize as soon as possible after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies in advance for such a cheap trick but this was the best I could come up with. It could definitely be improved though.

It would probably be fairly straightforward to embed this or extend Modernizr to build in a "finished" event in some way to do this more cleanly.

```
var completed = []
var complete = function(i) {
  completed.push(i)
  if (completed.length === 3) animationInit();
}

Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: App.isSmallScreen,
        yep:  '1.js',
        nope: '2.js',
        complete: function() { complete(1); }
    },
    {
        test: App.isTouch,
        yep: '3.js'
        complete: function() { complete(2); }
    },
    {
        test: Modernizer.csstransitions,
        nope:4.js
        complete: function() { complete(3); }
    }
]);
```